# PHP Sign Up Form - Safe and Secure?

Tags: php, forms, security, registration, code-injection

I just wanted to see how secure this form is, and if there are any potential problems.  I tried to add mysqli_real_escape_string to the Prepared statement but it gave me an error.

Also if I enter a name with an apostrophe, like "Drew's Company" it puts it in the database as

```
Drew\&#39;s Garage
```

Is that how it should be?

**Code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $errors = array();
    $clean_name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $clean_address = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $clean_zip = filter_var($_POST['zip_code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $clean_phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $clean_email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if($_POST['website'] != "") { $clean_url = filter_var($_POST['website'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); } else { $clean_url = ""; }

    $formatURL = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($clean_url, PHP_URL_HOST));
    $formatPhone = formatPhone($clean_phone);

    if($clean_name == "") {
        $errors[] = "Please enter your Business Name.";
    }
    if($clean_address == "") {
        $errors[] = "Please enter your Business Address.";
    }
    if($clean_zip == "") {
        $errors[] = "Please enter your Business Zip Code.";
    }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT zip_code FROM zip_codes WHERE zip_code = '$clean_zip'")) { 
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
        if(!$row_cnt) {
            $errors[] = "Please enter a valid zip code.";
        }
    }
    if($clean_phone == "") {
        $errors[] = "Please enter your Business Phone Number.";
    }
    if ($check_email = $mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM companies WHERE email = '$clean_email'")) { 
        $email_count = $check_email->num_rows;
        if($email_count) {
            $errors[] = "There is already an account associated with that e-mail address.";
        }
    }
    if(!checkEmail($clean_email)) {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a valid e-mail address.";
    }
    if ((strlen($_POST['password']) < 8) || (strlen($_POST['password']) > 16)) {
        $errors[] = "Your password must be between 8 and 16 characters.";
    }
    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']) {
        $errors[] = "Passwords do not match.  Please enter the same password.";
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        /* Create the prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO companies (company, address, zip_code, phone, url, password, email, date_created, role, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), 's', '1')")) {

        $hashed_pass = PassHash::hash($_POST['password']);

        /* Bind our params */
        $stmt->bind_param('ssissss', $clean_name, $clean_address, $clean_zip, $formatPhone, $formatURL, $hashed_pass, $clean_email);

         /* Execute the prepared Statement */
         $stmt->execute();

         if($mysqli->error) {
            echo $mysqli->error;
        }

         /* Echo results */
        echo "<div class='success'>Thank You!  You are now registered.</div>";

    }

}


}


if(count(@$errors))
 {
    $error_display = implode('<br />',$errors);
    echo "<div class='error'><strong>Error:</strong> $error_display</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: This might be better off for codereview se?

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally forgot about that site.

Comment: I add the ? because I honestly don't know.

Comment: Having a 16 char max for passwords is silly.  If anything this makes your system  less secure.

Comment: Anyway other than my 16char complain this looks fine,  but if you look at your response on SO,  you have people just suggesting vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks Rook. I will go ahead and change it.  What do you suggest I set it ot?

Comment: @Drew Maybe 512 or something very high,  this is only a problem if you are using a broken hash function like sha1 or md5 and you are worried about a length extension attack.  If you are using a salted sha2 then it should be any size and no one should be able to break it.

Comment: As far as your problem goes,  don't ask SO for this.  Just print out the value after every step or step though the code with a debugger.  You might have magic_quots_gpc enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be caused by using [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc), check your php.ini file and in case this flag is on - turn it off.

Comment: -1 magic_quotes_gpc is a horrilbe at stopping sqli,  he is using paramterized queries which is the *correct way*  also magic_quotes_gpc is being removed in php6,  because its insecure.

Comment: I didn't suggest using magic_quotes_gps, vice versa I am aware it is evil. I just thought that the problem might have been caused by <i>using</i> magic_quotes_gpc - and suggested Drew to check if this option was on (which could be the root of the problem)

Comment: oah i see, if you modify your post i'll take away the -1